# Attempting to create a powershell GUI to install a printer

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I put together to provide a GUI for installing a printer.  I seem to have an issue passing the variables from the Text Boxes on screen into the Add printer functions and tying them to a button.

I've tried a few combinations of Set functions and = functions to try and connect different variables but no success.  I also can't see errors as it doesn't show any error messages when the GUI loads.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text ='Printer Installation'
$main_form.Width = 600
$main_form.Height = 400
$main_form.AutoSize = $true
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "What is the Printer IP Address?"
$Label.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,10)
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$PrinterIPGUI = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$PrinterIPGUI.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)
$PrinterIPGUI.AutoSize = $true
$Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Text = "What do you want to name the printer?"
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,40)
$Label2.AutoSize = $true
$PrinterNameGUI = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$PrinterNameGUI.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
$PrinterNameGUI.AutoSize = $true
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,60)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
$Button.Text = "Run"
$main_form.Controls.Add($Label2)
$main_form.Controls.Add($PrinterNameGUI)
$main_form.Controls.Add($PrinterIPGUI)
$main_form.Controls.Add($Button)
$main_form.Controls.Add($Label)
$main_form.ShowDialog()

function Set-ActionOnClick{

add-printerport -name $PrinterIPGUI -printerhostaddress $PrinterIPGUI
add-printer -name $PrinterNameGUI -drivername "HP Universal Printing PCL     
6 (v6.7.0)" -port $PrinterIPGUI

}


$Button.Add_Click(

{

Set-ActionOnClick

}

)
```

I'd expect the issue comes from 2 things:

1. The Objects created to allow for text entry aren't able to correlate to the values entered on the text fields.
2. Because of that the function can't interpret the values entered on the GUI

Obviously there are no errors that present due to the GUI existing outside of powershell once it is run.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I approached this underneath a function approach and then just piped the variables for those fields out and it works.